# No debug trace when running mstest.exe from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, mstest, trace

I have a set of mstest unit tests, which use `Trace.Write` to collect some debugging information. And when I run it from VS2010 and then go to Test Run Details, there's Debug Trace section where I can see all my messages.

But when I run the same test from command line on the build machine, the trace is not recorded.

The things that I've tried:

- Make sure that I'm in Debug configuration
- */details* command line switch with *debugtrace*, *traceinfo* etc options
- I know about saving the traces to the file on the disk through the listeners, but I would like to find a solution to write

Has someone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Console.WriteLine` instead. I've had this problem before with `MSTest`, and using the `WriteLine` worked for me - in that there was output available in the test result view.

No idea what other things like `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine` didn't work, I never bothered to found out to be honest. (Well, I stopped using `MSTest` and moved to `NUnit`)

Comment: Just to double check - you're talking about command-line run, right? Not the VS UI. Yes, I know that Console.Write would work and write to VS Output window, but I don't need that, I need it to write directly to TRX.

Comment: Ah, ok, looks like it's completely two separate things for mstest - it writes Trace.WriteLine to Debug Trace section and Console.WriteLine to Standard Output section. So it might work for the command line thing. Thanks! I will let you know shortly if it works or not.

Comment: Yes, you were right! Console.WriteLine works from the command line.